# Помогите с программой для проекта на питон

Tags: python

У меня вопрос по программе с високосными годами. Я хотела представить `i` как

```
1682,1782,1882,..., year как 1582...1682,1582...1782,...,
```

и с каждым числом из диапазона year сделать проверку на высокосность.

Потом для каждого диапазона вычислить сдвиг, но почему-то не получается и выводится одно большое число.

Я пыталась сделать для каждого диапазона сдвиг с новой строки, и ничего не получилось, помогите, пожалуйста

```
number_of_leap_years=0
for i in range(1582,10083,100):
    for year in range (1582,i):
        if year %400== 0 and year%4== 0:
            number_of_leap_years+=1
        elif year%100== 0:
            number_of_leap_years+=0
    else:
        number_of_leap_years+=0
else:
    print(number_of_leap_years)
    a= year-1582+1
    b= 365.242374*a
    c= a*365 + number_of_leap_years
    d= b-c
    print(d)
```

Comment: давайте по порядку, что вы хотите видеть в перменных a, b, c, d?

Comment: странно видеть переменные ''number_of_leap_years''  и абцд вместе.

Comment: Немного непонятно, что такое сдвиг для каждого диапазона

Comment: Что за сдвиг? Что такое a, b,c и d? Строчки ``elif year%100== 0:
            number_of_leap_years+=0
    else:
        number_of_leap_years+=0`` можно полностью убрать, они ничего не делают, следовательно не только бесполезны, но и вредны.